# Jump back to the last position in PDF reader of Citavi 6

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

I hope this question is suitable to be asked here.

I am looking for an add-on to Citavi that could help to jump back to the previous view after clicking the hyperlink in the pdf reader of Citavi. I found this [lutz/JumpToLastPositionAfterActionExecutionAddon](https://github.com/lutz/JumpToLastPositionAfterActionExecutionAddon) might be the solution. However, I don't know how to make it work. There is no documentation for the installation instruction. Can someone with success please teach me how to use this tool?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's usually the same key command as 'go back to last page' in a browser. On Mac, that's Cmd/[ idk what it is for Win or nix.

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to create a new folder in your Citavi directory (usually here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Citavi 6) and call it "AddOns" (the spelling should be with a capital "O" and plural). Next you will have to go to [this GIT repository](https://github.com/lutz/JumpToLastPositionAfterActionExecutionAddon/releases) and look for your Citavi version (I guess 6.8). Download the JumpToLastPositionAfterActionExecutionAddon.zip file and extract it to the AddOns folder. In your ...\Citavi 6\AddOns folder you should find JumpToLastPositionAfterActionExecutionAddon.dll and another folder (...\de). In this folder you will find JumpToLastPositionAfterActionExecutionAddon.resources.dll.

Now restart Citavi (if you have not closed it already) and click on a link within the PDF reader. You should now be able to jump back with Alt + F3.

Comment: Thank you for the detail answer! However, it still doesn't work even though I completely follow your instruction. Not sure if it's due to my Citavi version of 6.10 (not 6.8). But in the repository it is stated the tool works with version 6.8 or higher.

Comment: Technical Information for the Citavi Team:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at JumpToLastPositionAfterActionExecution.Addon.MainForm_FormClosed(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(Message& m)
   at SwissAcademic.Controls.FormBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: (The error messages I got when restarting Citavi.)